# Input w/o enter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Is there a command for python shell that allows key input without using enter, like a tkinter bind or a cmd choice. any suggestions

I've tried a tkinter bind. pynput is not out for python 3.7 yet :(. any other suggestions? This did not work.

```
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>',Left)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right',Right)
def Right():
    if R == 0:
        X = X + 1
def Left():
    if L == 0:
        X = X - 1
```

I expected it to change x, but it didn't change.
(x is declared before these statements are called.)

Comment: You may be interested in the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module, which may cover your use case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Also check out [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/).

Comment: Your bound functions are failing due to references to an undefined local variable `X`.  You may also need to bind to the root window, rather than the canvas, so that the keys work even if the canvas has never been clicked on to give it keyboard focus.

Comment: How do I do that, Jasonharper?

Comment: Nevermind. Keyboard worked. I was having trouble installing getch.

Comment: How to use keyboard without hotkey @Green Cloak Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this if your os is windows

**msvcrt.getch()**
Read a keypress and return the resulting character. Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed. If the pressed key was a special function key, this will return '\000' or '\xe0'; the next call will return the keycode. The Control-C keypress cannot be read with this function.

check --> https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: I prefer keyboard, but getch is a popular recommendation.